# Theme dark turns textfield to white

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

when I try to use the dark theme, it turns the text field to white instead of a gray background.
Am I doing something wrong ?

1.Create a text field

2.Set the theme to dark

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark"
  }
});

export default function FilledTextFields() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <TextField id="myfilled-name" label="Name" variant="filled" />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-18s9j

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add something to control the background.

You can add `CssBaseline` to set the `<body>` background based on the theme:

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark"
  }
});

export default function FilledTextFields() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <TextField id="myfilled-name" label="Name" variant="filled" />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Dark theme with TextField]

Or you could wrap the `TextField` using `Paper` or some other Material-UI component that controls the background:

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark"
  }
});

export default function FilledTextFields() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Paper style={{ height: 100 }}>
        <TextField id="myfilled-name" label="Name" variant="filled" />
      </Paper>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Dark theme with TextField]