# TextField Material UI in dark mode

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a basic implementation of dark mode with material UI and React, the question is how to make *TextField* helper text, label, border changing according to dark and light mode toggled.
*TextField* is:

```
<TextField helperText='Sample text' label="Title" variant="outlined" />
```

Updated:
It's necessary TextField to have dark colored helperText, label, border in light mode, and light coloured in dark mode.
There is basic implementation of dark, light mode:

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper'
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch'

function App() {

  const [dark, setDark] = useState(false)

  const theme = createTheme({
      palette: {
          type: dark ? 'dark' : 'light',
      },
  })

  return (
    <Router>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Paper>
            <Header></Header>
<Switch checked={dark} onChange={() => setDark(!dark)} />
            <main className='py-3'>
              <Container>
                <Routes>
                  <Route exact path="/" element={<HomeScreen />}></Route>
             ...
                </Routes>
              </Container>
            </main>
            <Footer></Footer>

          </Paper>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Router>
  );

}

export default App;
```

Some of the elements correspond to light, dark mode toggling, *TextField* not.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, as answered here [Theme dark turns textfield to white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58343863/theme-dark-turns-textfield-to-white)
I added the helper text:

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark"
  }
});

export default function FilledTextFields() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <TextField 
        id="myfilled-name" 
        helperText='Sample text' 
        label="Name" 
        variant="filled"
       />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Put *CssBaseline* under *ThemeProvider* tag, for some reason no changes.

Answer (score 1):

If what you ask for is to change the style of hintText and label, you should see the [Customization](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#overriding-nested-component-styles) section of Material-UI

On the other hand, if you want to change the hintText itself on theme mode change, you have to use a global state to keep track of your theme mode.

```js
const App = () => {
    const [isDark, setIsDark] = useState(false)

    return (
        <TextField helperText={!isDark ? 'Sample text' : 'Some other text'} label="Title" variant="outlined" />
    )
}
```